# HTTP request status error

Tags: 7, blocks, ajax

This is the error shown in reports/status.

> Your system or network configuration does not allow Drupal to access web pages, resulting in reduced functionality. This could be due to your webserver configuration or PHP settings, and should be resolved in order to download information about available updates, fetch aggregator feeds, sign in via OpenID, or use other network-dependent services. If you are certain that Drupal can access web pages but you are still seeing this message, you may add `$conf['drupal_http_request_fails'] = FALSE;` to the bottom of your settings.php file.

What do I need to configure to prevent this error?

My website works well, but this error causes some problems, for example with the Quicktab module.

[image]

As you can see *Tab Content* disappeared and *Tab Weight* is changed to the select list. What do I need to do to fix this?

Besides that, I have other sites on this server; none of them has reported this error.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal cannot contact itself. The system module reports this error when a `system_check_http_request()`. Assuming this is the cause of the AJAX errors, you could try, as the error message suggests, to set `$conf['drupal_http_request_fails'] = FALSE;` in your **settings.php** file. This might fix the symptoms, but not the cause however.

The fix lies in figuring out why this check fails:

```
drupal_http_request(url('', array('absolute' => TRUE)), array('max_redirects' => 0));
```

It could be that `url()` is not returning your front page URL. If you have drush on your server, you can run the command `drush php-script my_test_script.php`. With **my_test_script.php** containing a simple test script:

```
<?php echo url('', array('absolute' => TRUE)), array('max_redirects' => 0); ?>
```

If it is returning the correct home page URL, another likely problem, since you're hosting multiple sites, is that your domain is not resolving the correct virtual host. You can test this with the server command:

```
wget -O- http://www.example.com/
```

If your site's home page HTML is output to the console that should tell you that the server can contact the resolve & connect to itself. If this is the case it might be something like a PHP config preventing retrieval of HTTP URL's.

Comment: Tried this. `url('', array('absolute' => TRUE))` gave me `http://default/` (obviously wrong and explains why site can't reach itself). However in the status report, the external cron link is displayed as `http://127.0.0.1:8888/cron.php?cron_key=...`. After I set `$base_url` to `http://localhost:8888` this error is still showing up. Any suggestions?

Comment: What if the test script results in "Call to undefined function url()"?

Comment: It sounds like you're using D7 `url()` is a D7 function; the parent question is implicitly a D7 question; the error is particular to the D7 system module.

Comment: @ShawnConn I am on D7, so url() should work. Perhaps related, I see I can't wget my own domain from the command line. I can only wget other domains. But I don't see how that would result in my getting an "undefined function" error when I execute the script with drush.

Answer (score 1):

Too late, but…
You could write the real IP of frontend but not resolved IP by DNS  into the /etc/hosts of backend (where php is working), e.g.

Real site IP: 32.32.32.32
Frontend's IP: 192.168.1.65
Backend's IP: 192.168.1.68

```
192.168.1.65      mysite.com
```